# Javascript date array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having some trouble with a Javascript function. Here is my code:

```
function date(){
  var d = new Date();
  var day = d.getDay();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var date = d.getDate();
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var days = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");


  document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = day[days] + " " + month + "/" + date + "/" +  year;
}
```

This function is returning "undefined 3/5/2013", but should instead be returning "Tuesday 3/5/2013." Is there an error in my logic? Can anyone help me find my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML =days[day] + " " + month + "/" + date + "/" +  year;
```

By mistake you have used

```
day[days]
```

instead of

```
days[day]

var day = d.getDay();
```

This method will return integer value for the day which you have to use in days[] array as index like days[d.getDay()]  and you are doing d.getDay()[days] Which is not correct

Comment: @user1157541 Always happy to help. Are you also working with jQuery mobile

Answer (score 1):

You code should be

document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = days[day] + " " + month + "/" + date + "/" +  year;

`days` is the array where `day` is the day of the week variable, you swapped those two variables

Answer (score 1):

`days` is the array and not `day`. You are calling `day[days]`. it should be `days[day]`.